# Django Queryset: Need help in optimizing this set of queries

Tags: python, sql, django, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to sieve out some common tag-combinations from a list of educational question records.

For this example, I'm looking at only 2-tag example (tag-tag) which I should get an example of result like:
"point" + "curve" (65 entries)
"add" + "subtract" (40 entries)
...

This is the desired outcome in SQL statement:

```
SELECT a.tag, b.tag, count(*)
FROM examquestions.dbmanagement_tag as a
INNER JOIN examquestions.dbmanagement_tag as b on a.question_id_id = b.question_id_id
where a.tag != b.tag
group by a.tag, b.tag
```

Basically we are getting different tags with common questions to be identified into a list and group them within the same matching tag combinations.

I have tried to do a similar query using django queryset:

```
    twotaglist = [] #final set of results

    alphatags = tag.objects.all().values('tag', 'type').annotate().order_by('tag')
    betatags = tag.objects.all().values('tag', 'type').annotate().order_by('tag')
    startindex = 0 #startindex reduced by 1 to shorten betatag range each time the atag changes. this is to reduce the double count of comparison of similar matches of tags
    for atag in alphatags:
        for btag in betatags[startindex:]:
            if (atag['tag'] != btag['tag']):
                commonQns = [] #to check how many common qns
                atagQns = tag.objects.filter(tag=atag['tag'], question_id__in=qnlist).values('question_id').annotate()
                btagQns = tag.objects.filter(tag=btag['tag'], question_id__in=qnlist).values('question_id').annotate()
                for atagQ in atagQns:
                    for btagQ in btagQns:
                        if (atagQ['question_id'] == btagQ['question_id']):
                            commonQns.append(atagQ['question_id'])
                if (len(commonQns) > 0):
                    twotaglist.append({'atag': atag['tag'],
                                        'btag': btag['tag'],
                                        'count': len(commonQns)})
        startindex=startindex+1
```

The logic works fine, however as I am pretty new to this platform, I'm not sure if there is a shorter workaround instead to make it much efficient.

Currently, the query needed about 45 seconds on about 5K X 5K tag comparison :(

Addon: Tag class

```
class tag(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField('id',primary_key=True,null=False)
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(question,null=False)
    tag = models.TextField('tag',null=True)
    type = models.CharField('type',max_length=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately django doesn't allow joining unless there's a foreign key (or one to one) involved. You're going to have to do it in code. I've found a way (totally untested) to do it with a single query which should improve execution time significantly.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

# Assuming Models
class Question(models.Model):
    ...

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(..)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='tags')

c = Counter()
questions = Question.objects.all().prefetch_related('tags') # prefetch M2M
for q in questions:
    # sort them so 'point' + 'curve' == 'curve' + 'point'
    tags = sorted([tag.name for tag in q.tags.all()])
    c.update(combinations(tags,2)) # get all 2-pair combinations and update counter
c.most_common(5) # show the top 5
```

The above code uses [Counters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), and [django prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) which should cover most of the bits above that might be unknown. Look at those resources if the above code doesn't work exactly, and modify accordingly.

If you're not using a M2M field on your `Question` model you can still access tags as if it were a M2M field by using [reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). See my edit that changes the reverse relation from `tag_set` to `tags`. I've made a couple of other edits that should work with the way you've defined your models.

If you don't specify `related_name='tags'`, then just change `tags` in the filters and prefetch_related to `tag_set` and you're good to go.

Comment: your model is somewhat different from mine, therefore i can't implement your solution. i just editted the question and added Tag class. do you think you can provide a solution based on that? thanks alot for your suggestion though, but this model will have too much impact on all my other codes. i will bear in mind to use this in future :)

Comment: @jdtoh can you please also edit your question with your `question` model? From what I'm seeing, my solution should still work for you. Foreign keys have a `reverse relation` which means you can access `tags`  as a collection on `question` with `question.objects.tag_set.all()`. Also, model names usually start with an UpperCase by convention.

Comment: @jdtoh see my edit, it should solve your problem with the models you've defined.

Comment: thanks alot Josh! it works! by the way, you might wish to edit your solution "combination" to "combinations" for future references. you saved me alot of troubles, can't thank you enough! THANKS!

Comment: @jdtoh just curious, how long does it take to run now? I would imagine 5-10 seconds max?

Comment: @jdtoh I would have thought close to instant. You were doing thousands and thousands of queries in your original version. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, I would keep things simpler and do something like this

```
relevant_tags = Tag.objects.filter(question_id__in=qnlist)
#Here relevant_tags has both a and b tags

unique_tags = set()
for tag_item in relevant_tags:
    unique_tags.add(tag_item.tag)

#unique_tags should have your A and B tags

a_tag = unique_tags.pop()
b_tag = unique_tags.pop() 

#Some logic to make sure what is A and what is B

a_tags = filter(lambda t : t.tag == a_tag, relevant_tags)
b_tags = filter(lambda t : t.tag == b_tag, relevant_tags)

#a_tags and b_tags contain A and B tags filtered from relevant_tags

same_question_tags = dict()

for q in qnlist:
  a_list = filter(lambda a: a.question_id == q.id, a_tags)
  b_list = filter(lambda a: a.question_id == q.id, b_tags)
  same_question_tags[q] = a_list+b_list
```

The good thing about this is you can extend it to N number of tags by iterating over the returned tags in a loop to get all unique ones and then iterating further to filter them out tag wise.

There are definitely more ways to do this too.

Comment: `t.tag = a_tag` this will always be `True`

Comment: i tried implementing this. may i know how come i have a syntaxerror: lambda cannot contain assignment?

Comment: may i know what does the final 'a_list+b_list' does? my code has this error - [unhashable type: 'dict'] which came from that line

Comment: Well if a_list and b_list are the filtered results, I'm just trying to create a dictionary which has q as the key and the combined a_list, b_list as its value i.e all tags with same question id in one